# In GDB, how do I execute a command automatically when program stops? (like display)

Tags: gdb, command

I want some commands to be automatically executed each time the program stops, just like what display does with x. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay I found it for myself. I post it here just in case someone else's gonna need it.
[CR]
define hook-stop  [CR]
    ...commands to be executed when execution stops  [CR]
    end  [CR]
'
See [this page](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks) of the GDB manual for more details

Comment: Why don't you write that as an answer, it can be useful for everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get gdb to do a 'list' after every step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362581/get-gdb-to-do-a-list-after-every-step)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the easy way I found out:

```
define hook-stop
  ...commands to be executed when execution stops
end
```

Refer to this page for details: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks

Answer (score 5):

Another "new" way to do it is with the [Python Event interface](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html#Events-In-Python):

```
 def stop_handler (event):
     print "event type: stop"

 gdb.events.stop.connect (stop_handler)
```

which will trigger the `stop_handler` function each the the inferior stops.

There are two other similar events type:

```
events.cont
events.exited
```

respectively triggered when the inferior is continued or exists.