# gdb not showing the line source

Tags: gdb

GDB is not showing me the line source after next/stop , and displays only line number and source file , like this :

```
(gdb) n
7   in test/test.c
```

whereas I expect it to display the current line , like this :

```
(gdb) next
17        char * good_message = "Hello, world.";
```

any settings in .gdbinit that might help me do this ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362581/get-gdb-to-do-a-list-after-every-step

Answer (score 5):

> whereas I expect it to display the current line , like this

On many platforms, such as `ELF`, the compiler records both the path to the source (`test/test.c` in your case), and the compilation directory, allowing GDB to display source regardless of which directory you invoke it in.

But many platforms are less flexible, and don't have a place to record compilation directory. On such platforms (e.g. AIX), you must either start GDB in the compilation directory, or tell it where to look for sources with `directory` command.

Comment: I was building debian package `exim4` from source (`dpkg-buildpackage`), and it knew path to the source, compilation directory. But somehow compilation directory didn't exist, and I had to descend into directory where path to the source resolved successfully (where executable was put) for it to find the source. By the way, upon reaching the breakpoint my `gdb` said, "exim.c: No such file or directory." Not just "1415 in exim.c"

Comment: Well, it appears the issue was with me trying to take a shortcut. Running `dpkg-buildpackage -T clean && dpkg-buildpackage -T build` in place of just `dpkg-buildpackage`. Because in the latter case compilation directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

Probably my answer may not be a perfect solution but the way you compile your source program matters. For example in my case if you do `g++ fib.cpp -o fib` and then try to run `gdb fib` it won't print the source code with `list`. Using debug flag `g++ -g fib.cpp -o fib` and then running with gdb solved my problem.