# Print local variables in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

How do I print the local variables in GDB every "next" or "step" command?

Is there a way instead of writing "info locals" every time?

Comment: The answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362581/how-to-get-gdb-to-do-a-list-after-every-step happens to apply here also, with a trivial adjustment

Answer (score 5):

If you can use GDB [TUI mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html), that's probably best. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375798/50617).

If you can't use TUI for some reason, this should also work:

```
# put this into ~/.gdbinit:
define hook-next
  info locals
end
```

More info on hooking commands [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html).