# gdb in backtrack

Tags: linux, gdb

I've just tried using gdb on [BackTrack Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) and I must say that its awesome. I wonder how gdb in backtrack is configured to act this way.

[image]

When I set a breakpoint, all the register values, a part of the stack, a part of the data section and the next 10-15 instructions to be executed are printed. The same happens when I `step` or `next` through the instructions.

I find this amazing and would love to have this on my Ubuntu machine too; how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Better question is how you got color output in gdb

Comment: By using [escape codes](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They seem to be using this .gdbinit file:

https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit/blob/master/gdbinit

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that this is done using a post command hook:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html#Hooks

inside of a system wide gdbinit:

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/System_002dwide-configuration.html

which may or may not reference shell commands and/or use gdb python scripts.
try:

```
strace gdb /bin/echo 2>&1 | grep gdbinit
```