# gdb split view with code

Tags: gdb

I was just debugging a program in gdb and somehow I found a new feature I've never seen or even heard of before, a split view where I can see and browse the code in addition to giving commands:

[image: Sorry about the picture, but ttys don't have screenshots.]

What is this? What did I do, or, more specifically, how can I get this split-screen mode again?  Is there a name for this mode, or somewhere I can read about how to use it?

Comment: For quick reference: You can exit this mode using any of C-x C-a, C-x a, or C-x A.` See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147117/how-to-exit-the-wh-mode-in-gdb).

Comment: But those are my emacs bindings....  thank `gud`.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It's called the [TUI](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) (no kidding). Start for example with `gdbtui` or `gdb -tui` ...

---

Please also see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301717)** by [Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245). It wasn't available in 2012 to the best of my knowledge, but definitely worth a look.

Comment: you can also use `layout next` after starting `gdb` normally

Answer (score 113):

You can trigger it dynamically by push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: thanks @user146043, this seems the only way if you are running screen at the same time as ctrl-a is the way to initiate screen commands!

Comment: Looks like you can close with that combo, too!

Comment: Ctrl+X O moves keyboard arrows focus to the next window.

Answer (score 49):

There are two variants of it.

1. to only see code Press

Press `CTRL` `X` together and then  `1`

2. To see both source and assembly

Press 'CTRL' 'X' together and then '2'

http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/ada/gnat/html/gdb_23.html

A screen shot of the view with code and assembly.
[image]

[Also check out this amazing Github project.](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the github project link. It is too awesome :)

Answer (score 30):

**GDB Dashboard**

https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard

GDB dashboard uses the [official GDB Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html) and prints the information that you want when GDB stops e.g. after a `next`, like [the native `display` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html).

GDB dashboard vs GDB's TUI mode:

- more robust, as it just prints to stdout instead of putting the shell on a more magic curses state, e.g.:

  - `vi` mode in `.inputrc` causes problems: https://superuser.com/questions/180512/how-to-turn-off-gdb-tui/927728#927728
  - program stdout / stderr breaks your interface: [GDB in TUI mode: how to deal with stderr's interaction with the ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291629/gdb-in-tui-mode-how-to-deal-with-stderrs-interaction-with-the-ui)
- highly configurable from Python: you can select what you want to output and how big each section is depending on what you are debugging.

  The most useful views are already implemented: source, assembly, registers, stack, memory, threads, expressions... but it should be easy to extend it with any information that is exposed on the GDB Python API.

  TUI only allows showing two of source, assembly and registers and that is it. Unless you want to modify its C source code of course ;-)

[image: GDB Dashboard screenshot]

I believe that GDB should ship with a setup like that out of the box and turned on by default, it would attract much more users that way.

Oh, and the main developer, [Andrea Cardaci](https://github.com/cyrus-and), has been very responsive and awesome. Big kudos.

See also: [How to highlight and color gdb output during interactive debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging/17341335#17341335)

Comment: There are not enough words to describe how awesome that is. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice, I just re-visited this question (or rather my answer) and found _your_ answer. Awesome. Will refer to your answer from mine, to make sure folks don't miss out on it.

Comment: Is it possible to configure it to split vertically as opposed to the horizontal split it does by default in the TUI mode?

Comment: @SamuelMyself I've never seen that, open an issue to double check, might be an interesting feature.

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 Well, found [this](https://gdb-prs.sourceware.narkive.com/FS3Z3lBr/bug-tui-17850-new-vertically-splitting-windows-in-gdb-tui). It was already requested 6 years ago but seems like no one's worked/working on it yet :(

Comment: @SamuelMyself ah, I meant on GDB Dashboard issues. It is 10x easier to add any new feature there (python vs C, new project vs dinosaur), and therefor 10x more likely to get done. Good to know about the GDB request though.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 17):

You can also start it from the gdb shell using the command "-" (dash). Not sure how to dynamically turn it off though.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest to use and remember.

Comment: You can exit by doing any of C-x C-a, C-x a, or C-x A. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147117/how-to-exit-the-wh-mode-in-gdb

Answer (score 14):

Type `layout` as a command in gdb and the split window will be shown.

Answer (score 10):

When GDB is in the standard mode, using `win` will automatically switch in the TUI mode.
Other command for TUI mode:

- `info win`
    List and give the size of all displayed windows.
- `focus next | prev | src | asm | regs | split`
    Set the focus to the named window. This command allows to change the active window so that scrolling keys can be affected to another window.

Read [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/ada/gnat/html/gdb_23.html) form more help.

Answer (score 2):

There is also interface tool for GDB called cgdb. Even with some color highlighting.
"ESC" to switch to code view, "i" to switch back to gdb

[image: cgdb]

Answer (score 2):

tui mode was clearly inspired by emacs -- I discovered it by accident when I hit ^X-o, which switches among split windows in emacs -- I sometimes hit that absent-mindedly when what I should be doing is switching to a different program.  Anyway, that leads to another feature not mentioned yet, that you can move the cursor from the code window (where you can scroll) to the command line, or vice versa, with ^X-o.

Comment: Obviously most of the programs from GNU have emacs like keybindings, mainly because of consistency reasons. I know there is a vi mode in bash, but that is not nearly good enough as emacs mode.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *(gdb) layout next* to split our interface. This command help us to see higher level language (eg. C, C++ ,etc.) code as well as assembly language code(ASM) with pointer [Click here to see split interface in C code, ASM, gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27B5b.png)