# how to exit the wh mode in gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

The 'wh' mode in gdb is not working very well for me. When I dump some data the command window and the program text window gets overlapped and it looks quite messy. I want to exit the wh mode without quitting the debugger and without killing the running program. I have set several breakpoints so I do not want to quit from the debugger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C-x C-a
C-x a
C-x A

```
 Enter or leave the TUI mode.
```

Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys).