# How to display the code window when debugging by GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

Can anyone tell me which command is used to display the source code when debugging through GDB.
Would be of great help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdb split view with code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115540/gdb-split-view-with-code)

Answer (score 27):

You can enter or leave the TUI mode with code window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> key binding. Or use `layout src` command to enter TUI mode. See other TUI [key bindings](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Keys.html#TUI-Keys) and [commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#TUI-Commands).

Answer (score 6):

The `list` command will show the code around the line where the program is currently stopped. If you type list again you'll see more.

Comment: list command shows the below output.                              (gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Comment: You must compile the program with debug information in order to see the source code while debugging. If you use GCC to compile, use the `-g` switch, for example `gcc -g example.c -o example`.

Answer (score 6):

- Start gdb using `gdb -tui`. tui stands for Text User Interface.
- Or, use 'ddd' -- a graphical front end for gdb.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the commands in the [source](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source.html#Source) category of the manual are for. More specifically, the sub-category [list](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/List.html#List) mentions the command `list`.

Note that gdb is not typically using "windows", it's a console application.

Answer (score 2):

By using `layout next` we can see the source code on different window. If the program didn't start running we will see empty screen for the beginning, when it starts the program will appear on different window.