# How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, arm, qemu

I'm trying to learn about ARM assembler programming using the GNU assembler.  I've setup my PC with QEmu and have a Debian ARM-HF chroot environment.

If I assemble and link my test program:

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
        mov     r0, #6
        bx      lr
```

with:

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld test.o -o test
```

Then load the file into gdb and set a breakpoint on _start:

```
root@Latitude-E6420:/root# gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1 (Debian 7.6.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
...
Reading symbols from /root/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8054
(gdb)
```

How do I single step the code, display the assembler source code and monitor the registers?
I tried some basic commands and they did not work:

```
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8054
(gdb) info regi
The program has no registers now.
(gdb) stepi
The program is not being run.
(gdb) disas
No frame selected.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/test 
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 26
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 26
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 16):

Your problem here is that you're trying to run an ARM gdb under QEMU's user-mode emulation. QEMU doesn't support the ptrace syscall (that's what syscall number 26 is), so this is never going to work.

What you need to do is run your test binary under QEMU with the QEMU options to enable QEMU's own builtin gdb stub which will listen on a TCP port. Then you can run a gdb compiled to run on your host system but with support for ARM targets, and tell that to connect to the TCP port.

(Emulating ptrace within QEMU is technically very tricky, and it would not provide much extra functionality that you can't already achieve via the QEMU builtin gdbstub. It's very unlikely it'll ever be implemented.)

Comment: A discussion of this is also here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=832710

Comment: related: walkthrough of actually setting up QEMU + GDB cross-debugging on an x86-64 Linux host: [How to run a single line of assembly, then see \[R1\] and condition flags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39503997)

Answer (score 13):

**Minimal working QEMU user mode example**

I was missing the `-fno-pie -no-pie` options:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb-multiarch gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf qemu-user
printf '
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    puts("hello world");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
' >  hello_world.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fno-pie -ggdb3 -no-pie -o hello_world hello_world.c
qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf -g 1234 ./hello_world
```

On another terminal:

```
gdb-multiarch -q --nh \
  -ex 'set architecture arm' \
  -ex 'set sysroot /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf' \
  -ex 'file hello_world' \
  -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
  -ex 'break main' \
  -ex continue \
  -ex 'layout split'
;
```

This leaves us at `main`, in a split code / disassembly view due to `layout split`. You will also interested in:

```
layout regs
```

which shows the registers.

At the end of the day however, GDB Dashboard is more flexible and reliable: [gdb split view with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115540/gdb-split-view-with-code/51301717#51301717)

`-fno-pie -no-pie` is required because the packaged Ubuntu GCC uses `-fpie -pie` by default, and those fail due to a QEMU bug: [How to GDB step debug a dynamically linked executable in QEMU user mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310756/how-to-gdb-step-debug-a-dynamically-linked-executable-in-qemu-user-mode/51343326#51343326)

There was no `gdbserver --multi`-like functionality for the QEMU GDB stub on QEMU 2.11: [How to restart QEMU user mode programs from the GDB stub as in gdbserver --multi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357124/how-to-restart-qemu-user-programs-from-gdb-as-in-gdbserver-multi)

For those learning ARM assembly, I am starting some runnable examples with assertions and using the C standard library for IO at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, gdb-multiarch 8.1, gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf 7.3.0, qemu-user 2.11.

**Freestanding QEMU user mode example**

This analogous procedure also works on an ARM freestanding (no standard library) example:

```
printf '
.data
    msg:
        .ascii "hello world\\n"
    len = . - msg
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* write syscall */
    mov r0, #1     /* stdout */
    ldr r1, =msg   /* buffer */
    ldr r2, =len   /* len */
    mov r7, #4     /* Syscall ID. */
    swi #0

    /* exit syscall */
    mov r0, #0 /* Status. */
    mov r7, #1 /* Syscall ID. */
    swi #0
' >  hello_world.S
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -ggdb3 -nostdlib -o hello_world -static hello_world.S
qemu-arm -g 1234 ./hello_world
```

On another terminal:

```
gdb-multiarch -q --nh \
  -ex 'set architecture arm' \
  -ex 'file hello_world' \
  -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
  -ex 'layout split' \
;
```

We are now left at the first instruction of the program.

**QEMU full system examples**

- Linux kernel: [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642)
- Bare metal: https://github.com/cirosantilli/newlib-examples/tree/f70f8a33f8b727422bd6f0b2975c4455d0b33efa#gdb

Comment: My answer on [How to run a single line of assembly, then see \[R1\] and condition flags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39503997) is another walk-through of qemu-user + gdb remote-debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Single step of an assembly instruction is done with **stepi**. **disas** will disassemble around the current PC. **info regi** will display the current register state. There are some examples for various processors on my blog for my [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) cross development tool chain project.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried them but with no success, I updated my post if you care to take another look?

Comment: @fred basset: you need to type run (r) after setting a breakpoint first. Should work then.

Comment: I tried running but it crashes.  Could this me a qemu problem?

Answer (score -2):

You should add the -g option too to the assembling. Otherwise the codeline info is not included.
That crash probably comes from running some garbage after the code lines.
Maybe you should add the exit system call:

```
mov eax, 1 ; exit
mov ebx, 0 ; returm value
int 0x80 ; system call
```

Comment: What does debug info have to do with assembly language level? What does your x86 assembly code have to do with ARM?