# Translate ARM binary to x86

Tags: ubuntu, binary, x86, arm

Is it possible to translate an ARM binary (shared object) to the x86 architecture?

Basically I want to use the ARM `libfoo.so` in a x86 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to get library sources and recompile.

You can also compile your application using `libfoo.so` for ARM and use `qemu` to run it on x86.

Mixing x86 and ARM code in one app is not possible.

Comment: Here is a detailed example of using QEMU with an ARM executable and C standard library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu/51310791#51310791

Comment: Wrong, it is possible - Intel's binary translator (libhoudini). But debugging it is a major PITA.