# Errors on assembling ARM asm on an x86 PC with GCC or `as`

Tags: assembly, arm, cross-compiling

So I have been doing an assembly tutorial, and I got stuck in the very beginning.

Project name: asmtut.s

The Code:

```
.text

.global _start

start:
  MOV R0, #65
  MOV R7, #1

SWI 0
```

Right off the beginning I'm welcomed by 3 error messages after I try this line:
as -o asmtut.o asmtut.s
asmtut.s:6: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
asmtut.s:7: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
asmtut.s:9: Error: no such instruction: 'swi 0'

I'm confused, because this is the exact code in the tutorial, and there it works completely fine.

Can anyone help me what could cause this?

Comment: Which `as` variant do you use? Which tutorial do you follow?

Comment: I suspect you're on an x86 Linux system, where `as` is expecting x86 instructions.  `#` is the comment character, and x86 doesn't have an `swi` instruction.  The tutorial probably ran `as` *on an ARM system*.  On x86, install a cross-assembler.  (And BTW, your label should be `_start:`, not `start:`.  It would still work, though, because `ld` defaults to the start of the `.text` section as the entry point if there's not `_start` symbol.

Comment: Thank you, that would explain it. Much appreciated. I'm doing Derek Banas's assembly tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViNnfoE56V8

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use an x86 assembler to assemble ARM code.  They use different instruction sets and syntax.

The native `gcc` and `as` tools on your x86 Linux system will choke, just like if you tried to compile C++ with a Java compiler or vice versa.    For example, `#` is the comment character in GAS x86 syntax, so `mov r0,` is a syntax error before it even gets to the point of noticing that `r0` isn't a valid x86 register name.

---

You're following a tutorial for Assembly on Raspberry Pi (an ARM architecture) on a x86-based PC.  **Either run `as` on the Raspberry Pi, or install a cross-compile toolchain for Rasperry Pi/ARM.**

Some Linux distros have packages that provide `arm-linux-gnueabi-as` and `...-gcc`.  For example, https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain has details for Ubuntu.

To actually run the resulting binaries, you'd either run them on your ARM system, or you'd need an ARM emulator like `qemu-arm`.  [How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu) and [How to run a single line of assembly, then see [R1] and condition flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503997/how-to-run-a-single-line-of-assembly-then-see-r1-and-condition-flags) have walkthroughs of doing that.

Comment: But note that you won't be able to run ARM programs on x86 without an emulator or similar.

Comment: @Zeta: I could post my version as a new answer if you want.  I didn't think of that; usually on old questions there's an accepted or highly-voted answer that needs improvement, and I was in that mindset while looking for a duplicate.  I don't personally do RPi development so leaving these links as part of a community-wiki answer for others to maintain seemed like a good idea.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah. Especially since its an ever-changing topic with new toolchains and such; hopefully the great picture doesn't change too much anymore. Just wanted to make sure that you gain the appropriate reputation. I'm fine with the answer being edited, it is, after all, a wiki answer :).

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll leave this one alone instead of cluttering the question with a 2nd answer.  I don't need another couple of nerd points that badly :P