# What is the simplest way to programming, debugging and executing risc-v assembly code using Qemu?

Tags: assembly, qemu, riscv32

I don't access to any RISC-V hardware, so, what is the simplest way to programming, debugging and executing risc-v assembly code using Qemu?

As I am reading the RISC-V edition of the Computer Organization and Design book, I prefer the 32 bit Architecture.

Comment: [How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310791) / [How to run a single line of assembly, then see \[R1\] and condition flags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39503997) are about ARM, but should apply equally to using qemu for RISC-V as a GDB-remote.

Comment: If your requirement is to use QEMU, then that's how to do it.  If you relax that requirement the RARS simulator is pretty good.