# MacOS Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective labs setup

Tags: c, macos, cpu-architecture, 32-bit, apple-silicon

I'm going to study this Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective, and do labs from http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/labs.html

But I can't figure out how to start, when I'm running "make" to compile lab, for example "datalab" I got an error

```
gcc -O -Wall -m32 -lm -o btest bits.c btest.c decl.c tests.c
ld: unknown/unsupported architecture name for: -arch armv4t
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [btest] Error 1
```

As I understand the problem with my system (MacOS m1), anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: What port of the compiler did you download & install, from where?

Comment: I don't think Macs support 32 bit builds these days.

Comment: @PeterCordes I haven't used VirtualBox since Apple silicon came out but it seems to be possible to install it according to this https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-apple-silicon-mac/ I presume OP could then install a 32-bit Linux per https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-distros-with-32-bit-support/ I'm not sure if these 2 assumptions are correct and don't want to send a new Linux user off on a bad track though.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: No idea, I've only casually used Macs, not for development.  I don't have one myself.  It's plausible VirtualBox could have an x86 emulator built-in, and if so I'd expect it to be able to emulate any mode, not just full 64-bit mode.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The CS:APP textbook uses x86.  Third edition uses x86-64; I'm surprised to see `-m32` in the command line.  I don't have the book, but I've answered plenty of questions about it: [Different asm on Windows x64 from a CS:APP x86-64 Linux example function for swapping a long](//stackoverflow.com/q/55274794) / [Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095394) ; it seems to be a good textbook, except the global edition where [the publishers broke the practice problems](//stackoverflow.com/q/57998998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using docker, I created a repository where I described the entire installation process, can be found [here](https://github.com/bmadone/csapp-labs-starter)

Answer (score 1):

No version of MacOS new enough to run on M1 hardware supports 32-bit x86; that was dropped a while ago. (You're on AArch64 hardware so x86-64 binaries only run using Rosetta 2 software emulation; it doesn't support old 32-bit binaries either.)

And M1 hardware doesn't support AArch32 state (32-bit mode), so native binaries can also only be 64-bit.  That's why your AArch64 clang complained that `-arch armv4t` wasn't supported.  (On MacOS, `gcc` actually runs Clang unless you've installed real GCC, e.g. via Brew.  That wouldn't help, you'd just get a different error message.)

---

For any of the CS:APP labs that need you to run or single-step 32-bit x86 code, you'll need to run some other OS inside an emulator, like perhaps QEMU if that can run on AArch64 MacOS.  A lightweight Linux install could work well, maybe just one you SSH into or use a text console (not a GUI desktop).

Or maybe qemu-user can emulate things for a single x86 Linux process under MacOS (instead of emulating a full system an running a full OS inside the guest).
Connecting to it as a GDB-remote is less simple than just running GDB on a binary.  *[How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590155/how-to-single-step-arm-assembly-in-gdb-on-qemu)* is the opposite question, using QEMU to single-step an ARM Linux binary on an x86-64 Linux desktop.  But there's no cross-OS aspect to that or [How to run a single line of assembly, then see [R1] and condition flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503997/how-to-run-a-single-line-of-assembly-then-see-r1-and-condition-flags) , just assembling and linking an ARM Linux binary.