# Using dynamic linker with qemu-arm

Tags: linux, arm, qemu

I have a very simple arm executable compiled with the `arm-linux-gnueabi` toolchain. I can execute it with `qemu-arm` without any problem:

```
$ qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/ ./a.out
Hello world !
```

Running the linker without any argument seems to work as well:

```
qemu-arm /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3
Usage: ld.so [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE-FILE [ARGS-FOR-PROGRAM...]
You have invoked `ld.so', the helper program for shared library executables.
...
```

However if I want the linker to run my executable, here is what happens:

```
$ qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/ /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3 a.out
a.out: error while loading shared libraries: a.out: cannot open shared object file
```

Here is the output of strace: https://pastebin.com/uJ7AhBdh

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: What is the output from `ldd a.out` ? (run within qemu)

Comment: I cannot run `ldd` but here is the output of `readelf -d a.out`: https://pastebin.com/G6TBxddi

Comment: looks like it cannot find `libc.so.6`

Comment: Can you post the output from `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr  -s '; '  \\012` ?

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf qemu-user
printf '
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    puts("hello world");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
' >  hello_world.c
qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf ./hello_world
```

and aarch64:

```
sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu qemu-user
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb3 -static -o hello_world hello_world.c
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu ./hello_world
```

both run fine.

Can you also provide your exact distro version?

Reletated for GDB step debug: [How to GDB step debug a dynamically linked executable in QEMU user mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310756/how-to-gdb-step-debug-a-dynamically-linked-executable-in-qemu-user-mode)

Comment: for static linking, you need musl: `apt install musl`, then `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ggdb3 -static -o hello_world hello_world.c`