# GDB debugging and disassembling i386 executable on aarch64 machine

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm running ARM Ubuntu on a virtual machine inside a mac M1.

I am doing a series of binary reverse engineering exercises where binaries have been supplied in i386.

At first I couldn't run or open a debugger on these files at all. But I found a way. I downloaded `qemu` and the linux/c shared libraries for the i386 and can run the executable like this:

`qemu-i386 -L /usr/i686-linux-gnu $BINARY`

I can also open the binary with `gdb-multiarch` and do `disas main` which shows some assembly for the function, but if I try to do `r` and run the binary inside gdb or add breakpoints or anything like that I get this error message:

```
warning: Selected architecture i386 is not compatible with reported target architecture aarch64
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug share library initializers and
track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Cannot instert breakpoint -1
Cannot access memory at address ....
```

Doing `set architecture i386` before or after attempting to run  doesn't change anything.

What am I missing? Is this possible?

Comment: You connected gdb to qemu, right? I don't see that on your command line.

Comment: @Jester I'm not sure how to do this...

Comment: Not sure which qemu version you are using but consult its manual and look for the gdb option. Could be `-s` or `-g`. Then in gdb connect via `target remote`.

Comment: Basically the opposite question from [How to single step ARM assembly in GDB on QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310791) but the answer should be about the same, just swapping arm for i386 as the target.