# GDB in TUI mode: how to deal with stderr's interaction with the ui

Tags: gdb, command-line-interface, tui

I am trying to use gdb to debug [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/). I prefer to use the tui mode because it allows me to see the whole source code rather than just a single line. But there is a problem: whenever the program `caffe` outputs something on `stderr`, the output distorts the tui interface. See the below snapshot for an illustration:

[image: normal]

[image: when there is output on stderr]

Is this an inherent limitation of gdb tui or is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to redirect the stderr to dev/null when running the app from GDB (in case you do not attach to a running process)? Just like: run $your_args 2> /dev/null

Comment: @bikjub That works, but more of a hack. Can't gab handles any program not silent?

Comment: How about using cgdb? It provides a very nice curses interface for gdb.

Comment: Any output from the target, even to stdout, is going to appear somewhere in the tui display; usually it appears at the top of the cmd window, near the status line, since that is usually where the cursor is just after you start or continue a process. You can use the `tty` command to have the target use a different terminal for its input and output.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion for workarounds. I filled a bug report and decide to switch to lldb.

Comment: @bikjub: I will accept the `cgdb` suggestion as answer. It does solve my problem.

Comment: You can also press Ctrl-L to refresh tui screen. But you will have to do it every time after tui gets distorted.

Comment: Late to the party, but sometimes in cases like this, I start the program on one terminal, then run the debugger on another terminal and attach to the program. If necessary I add a five-second sleep to the start of the program to give me time to attach before it starts doing anything.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @ks1322 you can press Ctrl-L to refresh the screen. Or define a [hook](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_189.html) in .gdbinit to refresh after every `next` command:

```
define hook-next
    refresh
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution to such TUI annoyances, and eventually gave up and moved to more reliable methods that:

- use the GDB Python API to get GDB data
- output some pre-configured views to stdout after every stop instead of putting the terminal in a magic ncurses mode

GDB Dashboard is one such solution, and I have described it at: [gdb split view with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115540/gdb-split-view-with-code/51301717#51301717)