# How to redirect a python.exe within a pre-existing venv's .env file

Tags: python, python-venv

Recently I uninstalled python and then reinstalled it to see what affects it would have on my code and ensure that I knew how to fix any path or directory issues. I mostly succeeded but am having trouble within my venvs. Testing out a basic django app I made any of my `python manage.py ...` code returns the error `No Python at '"C:\Python311\python.exe'`.

After doing some research it appears that the issue is that within .env\scripts there are two files called "python.exe" and "pythonw.exe" are causing the problem because they are trying to access a python.exe that no longer exists. (Note this is my understanding based off of [pythons venv document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) and I could be incorrect)

My question is what is the best way to deal with this issue. I see two options but am not sure how to accomplish either.

1. Fully reset the .env folder so it points to the correct python.
2. Just change those two files so they point to the correct instance of python.

So far the only things I have tested are running code outside of venv's entirely and creating new ones to run the code from. Both work totally fine so it is definitely something from the historic venvs.

I have also looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336676/why-do-python-venvs-have-a-home-setting-in-their-configurations-when-they-also) and I believe the two to be related but could be mistaken. Unfortunately it does not seem an answer was given there.

Comment: Option 1 sounds safest to me. I wouldn't expect existing virtualenv to work flawlessly after reinstalling python. Option 2 might work, but seems like a bit of reverse engineering is necessary to make sure it's working properly

Comment: No doubt about it, you should recreate the virtual environments.

Comment: @byxor Thanks for the advice. Out of curiosity when creating a new environment should I delete the old .env file and just create a new one in the same directory? Is there good documentation on how best to do this?