# Was GDB listing the code as I stepped through, or was I only dreaming?

Tags: gdb

Years ago, when I last had call to use GDB to debug a Linux server, I seem to remember seeing a listing of the code that was being executed. Perhaps it was just the current line +/- five lines or so. I think i also remember it redrawing the entire console, every time I executed a command, so that the code listing was always at the top of the screen.

Now that I am once again in need of GDB's assistance, is my memory playing cruel tricks on me? Or does such a mode actually exist?

The documentation I'm finding online just points me at the 'l' command to list code. That looks like it has some potential, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get it to dynamically update as I step/next my way through the code.

If it's significant, I'm running Ubuntu on a dedicated Linux machine, and (since the program uses OpenGL) the actual debugging is going on inside a Weston Compositor terminal window.

Comment: Are you talking about TUI mode? (There is a screenshot of TUI in action in https://stackoverflow.com/q/10115540/72178)

Comment: @ks1322, yes, I think that is what I'm talking about. Thanks!