# How to use colors in GDB with TUI or CGDB?

Tags: colors, gdb, tui, cgdb

I set a color for the **GDB** prompt by adding this line to `~/.gdbinit`:

```
set prompt \033[0;32m(gdb) \033[0m
```

This works fine in GDB, until I open the **TUI**. It then discards the colors and shows the raw color codes. The same thing happens if I use **CGDB**.

This is 2015. Is there any way I can have both colors in GDB and also view the source code I'm debugging in a subwindow (like in TUI/CGDB) at the terminal?

Comment: You can't in gdb with tui. See this bug https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14126.

Comment: Give up on TUI. Use GDB Dashboard: https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard

Comment: See also [this great answer about **extending GDB to display source code and to color GDB output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341335/938111)**. This answer is not about GDB TUI nor CGDB.

Answer (score 4):

This gdb bug was fixed a while ago (2018).  Also, gdb added colorizing to the CLI and to the TUI.  This first showed up, I believe, in GDB 9.1.