# Highlight a Specific Byte with gdb

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, cpu-registers

I am checking assembly code of a program and would like to highlight a specific value:

```
gdb a.out
b main
run
s ...                   until where I want to focus my attention
x/32 0x555555554b80     display nicely the bytes
```

Now, is there a way to ask gdb to display the output AND highlight if a byte is equal to the desired value (here 0x27) ?

```
x/32 0x555555554b80  |   0x27
```

By highlighting I mean put this byte in bold or green, or whatever that makes it stands out!

PS: I am aware about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging) but 1/ it does not answer my question, 2/ I would like to use gdb

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do this.  However, it can still be done with some scripting.

A relatively simple way, with a new-enough gdb, is to use the `pipe` command to pipe the output of `x` through a program that will do the highlighting you want.  For example, GNU `grep` can colorize the match this way.

Other approaches are possible.  For example you could write a new `x`-like command in Python, using gdb's Python API.