# How to adjust source code highlighting in GDB cli?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, gnu

I am using basic `GDB` CLI tool, no any TUI frontends. It highlights some parts of code with the same color as my terminal background making them indistinguishable. I know it is possible to disable source code highlighting but I would like to have it.
I didn't find much about this in documentation besides the fact that either **GNU Source Highlight library**, or **Python Pygments package** provide highlighting, but not a single word about how to check which of them `GDB` actually use or how to configure them and adjust colors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight and color gdb output during interactive debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging)

Comment: No it doesn't. It is about GDB output is general, while I've writen **source code**. Also it is ancient, both terminals and GDB changed since then

Comment: Not an ideal answer, but you can use `ldd` on your GDB binary to see if it links against `libsource-highlight.so.*`.  If it does then you can read about configuring libsource-highlight here: https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Configuration-files

Comment: It is usually easier to look into source code(which I eventually did) than scramble info bit-by-bit from ancient and barely related posts and articles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit `esc.style` in `/usr/share/source-highlight/esc.style`

GDB uses [source-highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight-lib.html) which should not be confused with similar tool called just '[highlight](https://gitlab.com/saalen/highlight)' and provided by some distributions including Debian and Ubuntu. It is possilbe to check if GDB is actually linked with it: there should be `--enable-source-highlight` line in `gdb --configuration` output. It is documented in `info source-highlight` and is configured by `.lang` and `.style` files. `esc` means 'escape' and used for output in terminal, `esc.style` usage is hardcoded in GDB sources, it would be more correct to check terminfo and use `esc256.style` if appropriate, but it is written the way it is written.

Comment: Note: You need to install the package `libsource-highlight-dev` https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsource-highlight-dev for the option `--enable-source-highlight` to work.

Comment: @user What if the output of `gdb --configuration` prints `--disable-source-highlight
` ? Can I change that or is that a compile time option ? If the latter, why is it disabled in ubuntu gdb's package ?

Comment: It is a compilation option. You need to ask Ubuntu developers why they disabled it. May be because they do not ship the `libsource-highlight` with Ubuntu and prefer their users to use Python `pygments` package highlight with gdb.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me is to update the gdb. You should compile a higher version of gdb distribution.
I solve the same problem using gdb13.2.
Install method can see:[how to install gdb](https://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-install-gdb)